# How to use testthat to test a package calling usethis::use_template

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I'm trying to use `usethis::use_template` in a function inside an R package and I'm running into issues when unit testing because the templates I put in my package's `inst/templates` directory are not found when testing with **testthat** even though they are found just fine during interactive use. I assume this 
is in some way related to use of `load_all` when the package is being loaded for testing? I looked at **usethis**'s unit tests and tried to copy some of the logic but it's pretty involved and I couldn't quite figure out what I need to do when testing so that I can test a function that calls `use_template`. Thanks in advance for any tips.